# Virtualbox causes automatic logout from Kali host when booting Windows guest and moving the mouse at the same time

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, login, kali-linux

I have been trying for several days  to get my virtual machine in Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.2 up and running but there seems to be something very strange going on with it.

Using Kali 2020.1 as a host I installed Windows 10 64b as a guest.  **Everything works normal as long as I don't touch the mouse during Windows boot.**

When Windows is booting, right before I see the login screen I get a black screen for a second or 2 and if I move the mouse at exactly that moment, VirtualBox crashes and I get logged out of Kali.  If I didn't touch the mouse, I get the login screen of Windows in my virtual machine.

Furthermore, after the crash of VirtualBox and being automatically logged out of Kali to the Kali login screen, I can't login again in Kali.  Every time I enter my login name and password I keep being taken back to the login screen of Kali.

I googled this and found I could go to another session in Kali, log in and remove the .ICEauthority file out of my /home directory, restart the gdm3 service and login again without being logged out automatically all over again.

My VirtualBox config: guest-additions installed, 2048 RAM and 2 cpu's dedicated, I/O APIC enabled, PAE/NX enabled, Hyper-V and nested paging enabled, 256MB video memory, VBoxSVGA, no 3D (that caused flashing), and other settings default.

What I've tried:

- checked if I have installed the latest Nvidia drivers (yes)
- disabled secure boot in the BIOS
- updated my BIOS to latest version
- disabled/enabled Hyper-V in BIOS
- tried different video settings of VirtualBox
- added user to vboxusers group

Is this a problem with VirtualBox, Kali, the Nvidia drivers, the mouse configuration, the login manager, Windows or something else?  Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently other apps like for example Gimp also caused a logout when starting.  After searching some more I was able to solve the problem.

Just open /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf and search for: #WaylandEnable=true.  Uncomment it, save and reboot and the problem is fixed.